# displaying two json values in a form at the same time?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I am generating 2 json object by using the java script mentioned  below.I am populating my json to the form fields, now the problem is I can display only one at  a time, how to display the other json in a form at the same time?

//first json :

```
{"vIRnumber":"195412","dReceivedDate":"2012-06-06","vDescription":"GP Coils","fThickness":"888","fWidth":"4566","fQuantity":"122","vStatus":"work in progress"}
```

//second json:

```
{"vIRnumber":"45","dReceivedDate":"2012-04-26","dDate":"0000-00-00","dStartDate":null,"nPartyName":"Aasha","vDescription":"MS Channels","fThickness":"1.8","fWidth":"1220","fQuantity":"34523"} 

        //**i am filling the fields using the javascript below:**

        var json =<?php echo($data); ?>;
        for(key in json)
        {
          if(json.hasOwnProperty(key))
            $('input[name='+key+']').val(json[key]);
    }
```

Comment: the first json is purposed to be the "Current values" and the second the updated values entered by user?

Comment: yes! first json is being populated from module A,and second json from module B

Comment: How do You imagine to display two different set of values in just one form at the same time??? My brain is not capable of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For displaying the first json you could add the values next to the form item for example

```
<label for="form-item-staddress">St.Adress</label>
<input id="form-item-stadress" type="text" name="stadress"/>
<div class="default">Default value from first json</div>
```

Load the first json in the div for displaying current value

For passing/saving the two json for submitting the form or processing other stuff you could try

```
<input type="hidden" id="firstJSON" value="FirstJSON"/>
<input type="hidden" id="seondJSON" value="SecondJSON"/>
```

or use 2 forms the first with the values of the first json, but can't be edited/submitted only for viewing/reference and 2nd form for editing/submitting.
You can try to do more like
comparison for changes